# Behaviour the source of the following dependency conflicts. tables 3.8.0 requires cython>=0.29.21, but you have cython 0.29.19 which is incompatible

Tags: python, cython, kivymd

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
tables 3.8.0 requires cython>=0.29.21, but you have cython 0.29.19 which is incompatible.

!pip install cython==0.29.19
```

Try to into in-order to convert my python code to `apk` on google `colab`